# Is there an equivalent to "-rdynamic" in mono?

Tags: c#, mono, ubuntu-12.04

I am porting an application from Windows to Ubuntu written in C#. The application is used to view video from a capture card. I have had to write a C# wrapper for a Dll in windows to access the API for the card, and have written a Wrapper for the corresponding .so in Mono for Ubuntu.

To build and run a C example app for the .so in ubuntu I had to pass "-rdynamic" to gcc to make the application run correctly, else there would be errors such as "Undefined symbol:  XMoveWindow". When I try to run my C# app I get "undefined symbol: XvShmCreateImage". I suspect that I need to pass something like "-rdynamic" to the compiler in mono, but I can't find an equivalent command for mono. Is there an equivalent command, and if so what is it?

Thanks in advance

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

This likely means that your .so library is miscompiled (it's not referencing the X11 libs).
You should either recompile this .so lib correctly or you can P/Invoke some function inside libX11 and libXshm before invoking this lib (the functions need not exist, but in that case you need to catch the exceptions, this is needed to load the libraries in the process so that the loader later can find the symbols exported by them).

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I have been working on another project for the last few days, so I haven't had a chance to look into this. I will get back onto the project later so I'll let you know how I get on.